# Run Tensorflow on Jupyter notebook but kernel dead

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I want to train a 5 Layer DNN using Tensorflow on Jupyter Notebook. It perform well on normal training.

But when I want to use Cross validation to find a great dropout rate. When training process, Jupyter say the kernel is dead.

The Jupyter log:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>     what():  Resource temporarily unavailable

My code is [here](https://github.com/phejimlin/Deep-Learning-Course/blob/master/HW2_DNN/HW2_DNN.ipynb).

I Google find out maybe it's because run out of memory. I try to reduce batch size and the error still occurred.

The code running on Ubuntu 16.04 and 32GB RAM with GPU 1080Ti. Enviroment are Python(3.5), tensorflow (1.3.0) & tensorflow-gpu (1.3.0).

Comment: Can you show whatever exceptions / tracebacks the kernel printed as it exited?

Comment: When jupyter show kernel dead, the exception is the log which I show above.

Comment: Can you file a bug with instructions to reproduce?

Comment: To reproduce, just need to run the Jupyter file which is the link I provided. The problem is that I can't finish cross validation part. When training, it will pop up kernel dead and stop running.
However, my friends work fine on windows. So, I don't know...

Comment: Did you try caling tf.Session.reset() between model training steps?